# Make a script for automatically updating the links from external server to our internal gitlab server

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I am working with a open source repo that I have cloned in my development environment. When I want to update the internal git repo, I enter the folder /home/pranav/Desktop/ and do:

1. git pull upstream master
2. Make edits, save, git add , and git commit all in your local repo
3. Push changes from local repo to your fork on gitlab.com ( git push origin master )
4. Update the central repo from your fork ( Pull Request )

But then, every morning I have to do the same thing for the updating the repo. This is quite troublesome.

Can I put this in a Bash script? I mean, if I write these git commands in the shell script, and run it, will I be able to update the repo automatically whenever there are any commits in the original repo?

other way: 1. git fetch- check for any commits
2. if commits found, then git pull
3. Go with stashing for any local changes.

I was thinking of writing something like this...

Comment: Yes you could put these commands in a shell script. Have you tried it? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Hi Alan, I did try them as a separate commands, But not able to get the automatic update on any commits from the original repo.

Comment: Why not? What problem did you encounter? What commands did you run?

Comment: I dont know how to write the thing in parenthesis. I mean the format for automatically updating.

Comment: So your actual question is how to create a pull request on gitlab? See https://glab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: script to update all directories on internal gitlab server with the external sources in the upper mentioned format.